# the definition of opinion-based

Tags: discussion, moderation, specific-question, close-reasons

Excuse me. An opinion-based question: Which question is more opinion-based: [liszt-s-566-schumann-widmung-v-s-liszt-liebestraum-no-3](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/14957/liszt-s-566-schumann-widmung-v-s-liszt-liebestraum-no-3) or [can-a-24-year-old-learn-to-play-violin-viola-proficiently](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/14911/can-a-24-year-old-learn-to-play-violin-viola-proficiently)? May I know whether the moderator's opinion based on this opinion-based label is well-reason sound or not?

Comment: Perhaps there is something going wrong in this Musical Practice & Performance stackexchange. It is hard to believe that one moderator's single decision can put on hold a question without being questioned its rigidity and necessity.

Comment: Music.SE is at an interesting point in its history.  We are very close to maintaining enough active users for the site to be self-sustaining, at which point moderators will be elected by the community.  The current, temporary mods have been *appointed* by Stack Exchange and are expected to have a bit of a firmer hand in shaping the site.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I agree with the moderator's decision. The original question asking

> what are the best versions of these two musics, such as in the youtube? I have watched several videos, such as Yundi Li, E Kissin, Lang Lang, Arthur Rubinstein

definitely was opinion based. Questions about what is "best" are generally frowned upon on StackExchange sites. See the [help center](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more detail. However, the edited version is much better and I have nominated it for re-opening.

Answering the question in your title, the definition of ["opinion-based"](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) is

> answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than on facts, references, or specific expertise.

---

I'm unsure why you linked the second question. It is not opinion-based and can be answered objectively.

Comment: Thanks American Luke. My objection is simply that the moderator holds unconventional power over the stack exchange, which is not reasonable and not necessarily beneficial to the site. To me, both questions are answerable, and both need NOT to be labeled as opinion-based. (Or both should be labeled as opinion-based.)

Comment: @Idear The mods do the job they are suppose to. They have a lot of power and they use it when necessary.

Comment: @Idear You might want to take a look at [this help page on moderators](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators). Pro Tempore Moderators are hand-picked by Stack Exchange employees to handle exceptional conditions. In this case, they simply placed your question on hold until the problems could be worked out.